# Unable to remote connect to Ubuntu system after Idle time in local network

Tags: networking, 20.04, remote-access, router, idle

Running Ubuntu desktop (personal use) as a server to host applications (Apache2) and Files

I usually connect to the Ubuntu system through Browser or WinSCP or SSH or WebDAV/CalDAV or from Android and it works fine. After some idle time like couple of hours, I cannot connect to it through anything

I can only reconnect to it after turning Ubuntu system Wi-Fi Off & On or Restarting it directly.

Things I checked/done:

- Set the Display and Sleep to Never in the Ubuntu system
- Checked the Router Admin Panel and it is the Ubuntu system is connected
  to it
- I am able to browse the internet from Ubuntu system
- Tried connecting from other devices like Android but not worked
- Ran a Watch Command set to run every few mins calling like
  example.com in Ubuntu system to keep network connection awake but to no avail
- Searched for solutions but most of it is pointed to setting SSH idle time or other

Ubuntu 20.04 and TP-Link Archer C20 Router. Ubuntu System is bind to a Specific IP Address(192.168.0.144) and I can connect using the IP Address.

Is it problem with Ubuntu System or Router? How I can solve this? It's been like a year and I still can't figure the issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How do you turn the device off? Is it a hard shutdown (you hold the power button until it shuts off) or are you able to do it through a UI?

Comment: Through UI as it is my personal laptop.